# Background in Constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to set background in my layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_backgroung">
```

But I've got the error:

> Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

File 'ic_background' is a vector drawable. Can it be the problem? And how can i solve it?
By the way, all images in my project are vectors, but there are no one problem with them (just use app:srcCompat and everything done) So I have no idea why doesn't it work with background :(
 Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Is it a full XML? What if change to LinearLayout? Also close tag. Check that you wrote drawable right: ic_background, not ic_backgroun**g**.

Comment: that's ok, i've already rename the file :) i have tried it with relative layout and it worked with no exceptions

Comment: Does your gradle include the constraint layout library?

Comment: please latest dependency of `constraintLayout` [this](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project)